# Get first day of previous month - month must be in 1..12

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I tried this and I am getting an error `month must be in 1..12`:

```
today_date = date.today()
# ERROR - month value becomes -1 here instead of 12
previous_month_4_start_date = today_date.replace(month=today_date.month - 4, day=1)
```

I can write some boilerplate code to fix this but looking for an efficient approach where if `month` is `-1` or `-2` or `-3` or `-4` then it should be replaced to `12` or `11` or `10` or `9` respectively.

Please help

**EDIT**

Thanks for helping with the month, how to take care of the year part since it will also change from `2020` to `2019` ? Please help

Comment: If you add 8, modulo 12 then add 1 to that?

Comment: @TomRobinson modulo would become a problem when value is 12 because 12 mod 12 = 0

Comment: Plus one at the end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* use `modulo` arithmetic for this problem, but first you have to convert the `month` number into a value which is valid modulo 12 (i.e. `0-11`) by subtracting one from it. You can then subtract `n` months from that value, take the modulus and convert it back to a `month` number by adding 1 again:

```
today_date = date.today()

previous_month_4_start_date = today_date.replace(month=(today_date.month - 1 - 4) % 12 + 1, day=1)
print(previous_month_4_start_date)
```

Output (as of `2020-04-14`):

```
2020-12-01
```

This doesn't deal with the fact that the year changes, to do that you need to compare the current month with the number being subtracted and if it is more than the current month, also subtract one from the year:

```
previous_month_4_start_date = today_date.replace(year=today_date.year-1 if today_date.month <= 4 else today_date.year,
                                                 month=(today_date.month - 1 - 4) % 12 + 1, 
                                                 day=1)
```

Output:

```
2019-12-01
```

**But**

That's the hard way to do it. The simple solution is to set the `day` to `1` and then use `relativedelta` to subtract 4 months:

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

today_date = date.today()

previous_month_4_start_date = today_date.replace(day = 1) - relativedelta(months = 4)
print(previous_month_4_start_date)
```

Output:

```
2019-12-01
```

Comment: Why would you have to subtract one?

Comment: @TomRobinson because `1-12` is not a valid number range for modulo 12 arithmetic. You have to convert it to a valid range first by subtracting `1` (to make it `0-11`), then you can do your modulo arithmetic and convert it back to a `1-12` range afterwards by adding `1` again.

Comment: Ah. The OP said in their post that the month value became negative one, but it clearly became 0. My bad.

Comment: @Nick How to take care of the year part? Year will also change from `2020` to `2019` correct? Please help

Comment: @user182944 see my edit - I've added a simpler solution using `relativedelta`.

Comment: @Nick `relativedelta` is awesome!

Comment: @user182944 yeah - had I realised what exactly you were trying to achieve I would have suggested it from the start. I got distracted by the other answer which used modulo arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The modulus operator is your best bet here. It does exactly what you need. You need to subtract 5 instead of 4 because the number needs to flow into negatives for the code to work:

```py
previous_month_4_start_date = today_date.replace(month=(today_date.month - 5) % 12 + 1, day=1)
# Returns: 12
```

Comment: Python handles negative numbers correctly with the modulo operator. No need to add 8, you can subtract 4 and will get the same answer.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that. Editing my answer.

Comment: I think his expected answer is December instead of January. So I don't think +1 is the correct solution. Note he stated `# ERROR - month value becomes -1 here instead of 12`

Comment: @user12758604 I'm pretty sure my code returns December, are you getting different results?

Comment: @TomRobinson I'm getting 01/01/2020

Comment: @user12758604 Hmm... given that, as OP stated in their post, `today_date.month - 4` is equal to `-1`. `-1 % 12` is `11`, plus `1` equals `12`, for December.

Comment: @TomRobinson How to take care of the year part? Year will also change from `2020` to `2019` correct? Please help

Answer (score 0):

```
#Try this to get the previous month's first day    

from datetime import datetime,date
today_date = date.today()
if today_date.month == 1:
    previous_month_4_start_date = today_date.replace(month=(12), day=1)
else:
    previous_month_4_start_date = today_date.replace(month=(today_date.month-1), day=1)
day_name= ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday','Sunday']
print(day_name[previous_month_4_start_date.weekday()])
print(previous_month_4_start_date)
```